# Getting data from Yelp API

Tags: php, yelp

I'm starting to look into Yelp API. When I send a search request I get a data returned in an array $response. So If I output it like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

I see results in the following format

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => OK
            [code] => 0
            [version] => 1.1.1
        )

    [businesses] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [rating_img_url] => http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png
                    [country_code] => US
                    ...
                 )
         )
)
```

So, let's say I want to get the country code, shouldn't I be able to get it with something like?

```
echo $response['businesses'][0]->country_code;
```

I'm not getting any results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $response->businesses[0]->country_code;
```

`businesses` is a property, not an array element.

Everything below `stdClass Object` are properties.

Everything below `=> Array` are Array Elements.

Let me guess, `$response = json_decode(...);` ?

You can tell this function to return associative arrays instead of objects by putting up the second parameter `true`:

```
$response = json_decode(..., true);
```

Then the values **would be** in:

```
echo $response['businesses'][0]['country_code'];
```

Comment: Dah... Coffee, I need more coffee! Danke.

Comment: @santa We all know that feel.